# Replacing string, integer, float in a file txt

Tags: python, replace

well, I have to find and replace a specific string, int, float in a text file.
For example :
    if I have this line **conf_send = 1234**
    I want the result to be like this: **conf_send = 24** or like this one **conf_send=1.1**
the code below doesn't give me the wished result :

```
import string
file = open ('a.txt','r')
txt = file.read()
file.close()#closing opened file
#replacing procedure
replace = string.Template(txt)
replaced = replace.substitute(envoi = 'newstring')
```

when I print the result (print replaced) it show me that replacing procedure is done, but 
when I open the file a.txt, I found that nothing is happen.

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: The file is the same because you are not touching it. You need to write back the new content to it.

Comment: I can replace string, by using replace method but the problem is how to identify the right string to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace specific text in a file a suggest the use of the module [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('filename', inplace=True):
    # do what you need to do and then just print:
    print line.replace('1234', '24')
```

Comment: Thank u Enrico, it's really working good, but after execution, I cant modify any more the text file, I got this msg "Error writing file.txt: Permession denied".

Comment: Citing the docs for `fileinput`: "If you just want to read or write one file see [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)."

Comment: ok that's good opening file as SUPER USER solve the problem, Special thanks to Enrico.basics